# How to access request context in Flask after_request?

Tags: python, flask

So, there are 3 concepts:

- Application Context - stored in `g`
- Session Context - stored in `session` (stores data across requests, may use cookies)
- Request Context - ???

Couldn't find in Flask's docs.

I also looked in the guide: https://pythonise.com/feed/flask/python-before-after-request - they seem to confuse request context with session context.

My code (its pattern):

```
def handle_path1(event, request_context):
    return gen_response(event, request_context)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/path1', '/path1', handle_path1)

@app.after_request
def after_request_response_audit(response):
    request_context = ???SOMEHOW_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT???()
    logging.info('%s %s' % (
        request_context['response_measure1'], 
        request_context['response_measure2']
    ))

@app.after_request
def after_request_response_measure2(response):
    request_context = ???SOMEHOW_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT???()
    request_context['response_measure2'] = measure_response2(response)

@app.after_request
def after_request_response_measure1(response):
    request_context = ???SOMEHOW_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT???()
    request_context['response_measure1'] = measure_response1(response)
```

The question is how to do `???SOMEHOW_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT???()`.

Comment: You can just use the Flask request module ```from flask import request``` and then access it with something like ```request.data```

Comment: @KevinMüller this seems hackish, as according to docs `request.data` may contain incoming data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this! It is thread safe

```
from flask import request
@app.after_request
def after_request_response_measure1(response):
    request_context = request # Not needed
    request_context['response_measure1'] = measure_response1(response)
```

Comment: the `SOMEHOW_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT` is unknown here

Comment: The **SOMEHOE_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT** is your any function, I mean all request context is in **request** itself.

Comment: You can find all properties of **request** [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request)

Comment: in which field of **request** can I store custom handling-scoped data?

Comment: I updated the example above to make it clear that `SOMEHOW_GET_REQUEST_CONTEXT` isn't needed.  I think he was trying to say that you can still use `flask.request` even in an `@app.after_request` function.